# How should I investigate an electric feeling from an oven?

Tags: electrical

Apologies if this is off topic. I couldn't quite work it out from the asking help.

I have an oven with a metal door. When the oven is switched on at the wall, I can feel an electric 'feeling' like vibration if I trail my finger across the door. When it's turned off, I can't feel anything.

I am not 100% sure that it's actually there, and not my imagination. How exactly would I find out if some current is leaking to the oven door? The oven is fully working and has no problems that I can see.

Comment: Like the others said, you'll need to test it - preferably with a voltmeter. However I will say that 120V or (definitely not) 240V, you'd hopefully know what you're touching. If it shows up when plugged in only, then it must be electricity. Just don't touch it.

Comment: You should call an electrician. it could be any number of things including a short or misconfigured wiring connections inside the oven, or a bad ground connection or all of the above. But if there's no tingle, then you turn the switch on and there's a tingle, that's electricity and messing around with it the wrong way could really ruin your day (or longer).

Comment: Yeah, I've called the spark. Will update with what he says.

Answer (score 2):

as electricity can kill or cause fires, you would be wisest to get an electrician or appliance service guy to have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You need to test for voltage from the oven door to ground. This will require a voltage tester so if you don't own one you would need to borrow one or buy one.

If you don't feel comfortable pursuing some wiring changes you may want to call an experienced electrician. If the oven is mis-wired it will need to be fixed.

If the oven is close enough to a grounded outlet you could test between the door (or metal frame of the oven) and the ground prong on the outlet. or if you have a metal water piping system you could test between the oven and the kitchen sink faucet. The key here is you are trying to determine if the frame of the oven is properly grounded. If it is not it will have to be re-wired.

You should probably not use the oven until it is investigated and repaired.

Good luck!

Comment: Please, I would not recommend messing around with one hand near this oven and one hand near your sink/faucet. It would be bad if the oven is electrified due to a short and one were to inadvertently create a path to ground through one's body.

Comment: True there is some danger involved in taking a voltage reading. Ne Mo, if you do not feel comfortable with this process then you should call a professional.